# C++ 11/14/17 does support "auto new"

Tags: c++

Declare a pointer like as

```
CAMArrayRefHash<AMPSDK::H264Video::SEQ_PARAMETER_SET_RBSP>* h264_sps;
```

When make a instance for it finally:

```
h264_sps = new CAMArrayRefHash<AMPSDK::H264Video::SEQ_PARAMETER_SET_RBSP>();
```

Is there a simple way for it in C++11/14/17? for example, auto new

```
h264_sps = auto new;
```

Comment: updated the answer now I realise what you want

Comment: Maybe typedef that into something more managable. Would also be clearer as you'd still be able to see what is beeing allocated instead of a obscure auto new which tells nothing if it were to work.

Comment: Swap the `auto` and the type! `auto *h264_sps = new CAMArrayRefHash<…>();`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant that's ok only if it's a local variable

Comment: @blackibiza yes, but at least it works *then.*

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  int* p;

  p = new std::decay_t<decltype(*p)>;
  p = new std::iterator_traits<decltype(p)>::value_type();
}
```

or we can get creative with template argument deduction:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template<class Ptr, class...Args>
Ptr make_new(Ptr& p, Args&&...args)
{
  p = new std::decay_t<decltype(*p)>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return p;
}

int main()
{
  int* p;

  // warning: initialises p  
  make_new(p);

  // initalise p and return a copy to ease use in algorithms  
  auto pcopy = make_new(p);
}
```

Comment: That wasn't the question though; They asked if there was a way to replace the type that new asks for. Presumably they already knew about auto otherwise they wouldn't have asked.

Comment: `iterator_traits` seems like a very confusing way to get a type that has nothing to do with iterators.

Comment: It is still a little long, for example, p is a deep structure, struct A { struct B {Struct C....};};} a.b.c.....p = new std::decay_t<decltype(*a.b.c.....p)>;

Comment: @ravin.wang  `make_new(p)` is a little long? The template declaration only has to happen once per program so you can tuck it away in a utility header file. It also works for any number of arguments so it will never need to be touched again. Short of a direct brain-to-computer link I can't think of a way to make it shorter, other than renaming `make_new` to `mn`

Comment: make_new(p) is ok, but it is not a standard function or keyword, anyway I think your answer is a good point for me.

Comment: @ravin.wang i see. No, there is no direct language support for what you want to do. Normally we would typedef the complex type with a more manageable typedef. e.g. `using myhash = CAMArrayRefHash<AMPSDK::H264Video::SEQ_PARAMETER_SET_RBSP>;` and then use the `myhash` typedef

Answer (score 2):

If you're on C++11/14/17, just use **[smart_pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)** combined with keyword **[using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)**:

```
using RBSP = AMPSDK::H264Video::SEQ_PARAMETER_SET_RBSP; 

//if it's shared resource use **shared_ptr**
std::shared_ptr<RBSP> h264_sps{};
//if it's owned only by a class / struct,
std::unique_ptr<RBSP> h264_sps_unique{};
//after some lines of code or in another file...
h_264_sps = std::make_shared<RBSP>();
//Only in C++14/17:
h264_sps_unique = std::make_unique<RBSP>();
```

With this solution, you avoid *naked pointers* (which are a considered a [bad practice](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) with modern C++) and you have to type less in every occurrence of your pointer.